# React-native Fetch GET, while passing request items to the url

Tags: react-native, django-rest-framework

I have a Django-REST API that I am trying to access with a React-native app. I would like to achieve the same result that the command line

```
http GET http://mywebsite.com/api param1=value1 param2=value2
```

but using the `fetch()` function from the [networking tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html). How can I specify the request items to the `fetch` while using the `GET` method?

EDIT: my goal is to able to perform a [token authentication to a django rest API](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication)  which need these request item for the page to be accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetch()` uses the exact `URL string` you provide to perform the request.

Include **URL params in your url** like when you are calling `fetch()`

```
fetch("http://whatever.xyz?param1=1&param2=2")
```

Comment: This methods allows me to send some parameters to the API but they're not exactly the same as request items. To perform a Token Authentication,  for example, I won't even reach the state where I can read these params if I didn't send the token along with the request, like this:

`http GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/example/ -H 'Authorization: Token 9944b09199c62bcf9418ad846dd0e4bbdfc6ee4b'`

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication

Comment: @RyanPergent you can add the `Authorization` param!

Comment: It doesn't work. When I add the Authorization param as such: ?`Authorization=Token%20ba5d691212cc94a6e0267c4e2117fb798bd4ec` it returns a HTTP 403, forbidden.

Comment: Okay, I finally got it. It's because the Authorization had to be a header!

Comment: @RyanPergent yeah sorry for the delay getting back to you, you should provide the `Authorization ` header in `fetch` options!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to handle this is by using something similar to the following function

```
 function apiCall() {
 return fetch('http://mywebsite.com/api/?param1=value1&param2=value2')
 .then((response) => response.json())
 .then((responseJson) => {
 return responseJson.movies;
 })
 .catch((error) => {
 console.error(error);
 });
}
```

Comment: But this method won't work in the case of an authentication isn't it? If for example i need to pass a username and password or even a token along with the url for the api to allow the request. As required in the django rest framework http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#how-authentication-is-determined

Comment: You can put authentication tokens or passwords in the BODY of the request.

For example: ------>
  let options = Object.assign({ method: verb }, params ? { body: JSON.stringify(params) } : null );


Then use:-------> fetch(apiEndpoint,options )

were params are the key-value data you like to pass with the request

Comment: If you are having trouble there is a simple example in the documentation for POST request with headers and, body parameters.  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html#using-fetch